# How to add ":AFTER" content with CSS to element without content

Tags: html, css

I have a `<span>` element in HTML which has a class and I can identify it. It is also empty. I'd like to be able to replace the empty `<span>` with some content, and I was thinking of using a CSS `:after` to do so. But it seems to be a problem for empty elements.

Is there something I'm missing or another way to approach this? I can't change the HTML, so it's either CSS (preferred) or jQuery. I know how to do this in jQuery, but was hoping to do it in CSS.

Comment: CSS's `:after` should be used extremely sparingly. CSS is for presentation and not for content. JQuery sounds like a better solution.

Comment: Of course `:after` works with “empty” span elements as well. Why it doesn’t in your specific case, is impossible to tell without any code. (-1 for not showing any code or real example. With 2k+ rep you should know that already.)

Comment: I don't disagree with Michael's comment above but there should not be any problem adding pseudo-element to an empty span. Can you show the problem in a demo?

Comment: create a jsbin please

Comment: Michael - I wouldn't normally, but this is a solution that we'd prefer to work if javascript is disabled. CSS "after" works better there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do use like this as well:

```
:empty::after {
    content: "Your content";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following CSS::

```
span.classname::after{
 content: "The content you want to add";
 display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, after looking at the code again, I realised that the original developer of the solution had mispelt a style name, which I had correctly spelt, and so wasn't being selected. Yes, it works just fine on empty content.

Comment: I know you'd be having your reasons for adding an "answer" but personally I think it would have been a better idea to remove the question given the cause is a typo error. I am going to vtc as one and some others may even downvote you further. Its just a suggestion though :)